# PHP Getting Random Gives Blank Results

Tags: php, function, random

This is part of a WordPress plugin script. I am trying to edit it to get my own custom title. The code below returns the text:

> random_phrase

The `'post_title' =>` line does not get a random line from the quotes.txt file. Any idea on why this is not working ?

```
function random_phrase () 
{ 
$quotes = file ("quotes.txt");
$num = rand (0, intval (count ($quotes) / 3)) * 3;
echo $quotes[$num] . "<br>" . $quotes[$num + 1];
}

// and create a post
$wpvt_post = array(
    'post_title' => random_phrase,
    'post_content' => $post_content,
    'post_author' => $item['item']['post_author'],
    'post_status' => $item['item']['post_status'],
);
```

Comment: `var_dump($quotes); var_dump($num);` basic debugging please

Comment: $num + 1 will cause problems if the first random selection is the last of the array, then it will try to select the next one, but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
'post_title' => random_phrase(),
```

It also shouldn't be `echo` but `return`.
And be warned that your random index generation will bug.

Comment: Your suggestion is getting the line from the text file. I am getting some weird errors though. Getting two titles instead of one. Do you have a better suggestion for the code? Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of  . "<br>" . $quotes[$num + 1] ? IE: return $quotes[$num]; And for the rand you should just use rand (0, count ($quotes));

Comment: I believe I got it. Thank you for your help.